# If Lot went to Zoar, why did his daughters think no one was left on earth?

Tags: genesis, abraham, sodom-and-gomorrah, lot

Did Lot actually go to Zoar? Bible text would suggest yes. However, why would the daughters think no one was left on earth? Genesis 19:31. It seems to me they arrived in Zoar and later left. Although it doesn't indicate how long nevertheless I'm assuming there were people there.

Now, **if** they actually never got there it makes sense. However, Genesis 19:23 seems to suggest they did actually go to Zoar.

Comment: You should consult other bible versions as well, as the old KJV can be misleading in interpretation. Earth should not be understood as whole world there, the words in Hebrew and Greek dont necessarily mean whole world, but just Land.

Answer (score 2):

Let me list the facts of the narrative as recorded in Gen 19:

1. V21-23 - Lot and his two daughters reached Zoar, twice
2. V30 - "Lot and his two daughters left Zoar and settled in the mountains ... where they lived in a cave."

Verse 31 is the verse in question; so here is my literal translation:

> And said the firstborn to the younger: "Our father [is] old; and man
> none on/in the land to come in to us as the custom of all the land."

The important word here is אֶרֶץ (erets) = land or earth as in soil.  The word almost never means "planet earth".

Thus, the comment of the older to the younger daughter is simply saying there are no local men for sire children by us.  This was true because the big cities of Sodom and Gomorrah had been destroyed and Zoar may have also been deserted out of fear (see V30).  They were living in a remote and isolated place.

It certainly does not mean that no men were left in all the world, just no men left in that part of the land.

Indeed, Abraham and his large household (including the 318 fighting men recorded in Gen 14:14) remained untouched by the conflagration as recorded in V27.

Answer (score 0):

Ch19 v30 says Lot was "afraid to dwell in Zoar". If it was the physical environment that was dangerous, because the "brimstone and fire" was attacking a wide region, isn't it plausible that the inhabitants themselves had fled before Lot got  there?

Comment: Vs. 23 says the sun had risen when Lot entered Zoar however you are correct it doesn't say that anyone was actually there. Thank you,

Comment: I don't think they fled in fear of fire and brimstone before Lot arrived because the fire and brimstone started raining only after Lot arrived in Zoar. v22: "I[God] can do nothing till you arrive there[Zoar]".

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking about that as well. I guess my whole question is Did Lot actually arrive in Zoar? I read some commentaries etc.. that say yes but others seem to think he doesn't. I always assumed he did & later went to the mountains.